# How to stop execution of Get-AzureWebSiteLog in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm running the powershell commandlet

```
Get-AzureWebSiteLog -Name "myfunctions(Staging)" -Tail -Message Information
```

It streams logs to me for Azure websites (functions).

However everytime I deploy I need to restart the service I need to stop it and <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> takes forever and it's super frustrating since I have to do this several times a day.

Short of closing powershell and reopening it with a shortcut is there some other way I can force quit the execution of the commandlet? I can't find any advice other than <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>.

Comment: so the command described is it always running even during the deployment?

Comment: I'm in early development and I just want to upload to my Azure staging environment and watch what comes in.

Comment: if it's running all the time why don't you use stop-process (with ps remoting) and kill your process just before your deployment triggers.